# how to programmatically determine if android is connected to wifi?

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I'm trying to setup a test for automation on a new android app that I'm developing but having a bit of trouble with one of the apis

The problem i'm facing is I want to start the test AFTER wifi has a connection, not when its in the connecting state. I have tried two solutions but had no luck and test seems to start before my android device is fully connected (no x on the wifi bars)

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(state);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
while (wifiInfo.getSSID() == null) {
    Log.i("WifiStatus", "Here I am");
    Thread.sleep(Time.ONE_SECOND);
    wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

This is my first implementation trying to get the SSID to determine if connection has been established. but the test still starts before a full connection has been made and fails the setup.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = 
    (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(state);
while (!networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    Log.i("WifiStatus", "Here I am");
    Thread.sleep(Time.ONE_SECOND);
    networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}
```

The second implementation i'm using connectivity manager instead and using `isConnected()`.

Does anyone have another method I can possibly check to determine if the device has fully established a connection with wifi?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of ping to google.com?

Comment: thanks! i actually had to resort to that method to determine a full connection to the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a "ping" if you want to call it that.  If the connection completes, you know you are still connected.  If you get an `IOException` or a `NullPointerException`, then you probably timed out and are not connected anymore.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        urlConnect.getContent();
        System.out.println("Connection established.");
    } catch (NullPointerException np) {
        np.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How would this tell a wi-fi connection from a 3G or EDGE connection?

Comment: The question asked to determine if the device was connected to **WI-FI**, not to a cellular network.

Comment: thanks syb0rg! helped a lot. wasnt sure if the api i was using already took care of it or not but this is a workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of getting the networkinfo manually... try getting the 'currently active' network and checking if that is the wifi. Note: If it is null that means that no network is connected... so it replaces the isConnected call.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = 
    (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo current = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isWifi = current != null && current.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

Comment: For some reason when I used this, I ran into the issue where it would connect but have limited connectivity and continue with the test which I did not want it to do :(

Comment: @Felix i want when android devices connected in WI-FI That a time i want to calling API for update database

Answer (score 0):

`wifiManager.getWifiState()== WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED` when you get full connection