# How test if an open connection is working?

Tags: android, connection

We are developing some internal apps for mobile devices that are connected to internal wifis. We have some problems because we are only checking if the devices are connected using ConnectivityManager. But we need to check not only if there is connection, we need to check that the connection between the device and the server is working.

The problem is that ConnectivityManager tell us that the wifi is connected. But if the device is in an area with little coverage the app have errors trying to connect.

How can we easily check that the connection we have open against the server is still responding correctly? For example, one of the applications the connection is open against a SQL Server. Is there any way to check that we get to the server and it gives us an ok, and that we are not losing the connection and the packages because of the low coverage?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pinging the server if you receive a `NullPointerException` or `IOException` most likely there is no connection or connection timed out.
you can read more here [an answer to similar question by syb0rg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268824/4833466). Also remember to wrap this piece of code in an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` to prevent your app from crashing.

```
try {
    //replace URL with your domain
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(1000);
    urlConnect.getContent();
    System.out.println("Connection established.");
} catch (NullPointerException np) {
    np.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```